# Email friend for each Custom Post Type posts on a page

Tags: custom-post-types, email

I have a Custom Post Type called 'Property'. I display a list of CPT properties on a page: 10 per page with pagination.

I would like to add an "Email friend" link to every property on the list, so a user can email that property url to multiple email addresses easily.

Is there a plugin that can do this? Otherwise, what's the best approach for to do it?

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: @anu, yes totally my bad - gonna try to sort it out. Sorry everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a simple "mailto" link. Not sure this is the best approach for this question, but it seems to work. If someone knows a better solution (ideally plugin or code) please feel free to add it.

Thanks,
Dasha

Answer (score 1):

I use the service over at here: http://www.freetellafriend.com/ It allows not only sending email to a friend but also allows the user to use their address book from hotmail gmail and yahoo mail. Plus it allows your site submission to 100's of social network sites